# Placing multiple instances of the same image generated by javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am making a test page where the user enters in how much sugar they have consumed and then generates a graphic meter which shows them how this value corresponds to daily recommended sugar intakes.

The meter itself is a graphic which I have separated into three parts: a beginning cap, a middle, and an end cap. See the following link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bVUwK.jpg

My issue is that the code I am currently running does not want to append the containing div with more than one instance of the middle section of the bar. In this case it is enough for me to just change the width of that part of the graphic, but I would rather be able to just duplicate the graphic x times until it fills in the proper amount of the bar. Each part of the graphic (beginning, middle, and end) is 10px wide.

NOTE: I am trying to code it so that it will fill up the meter dynamically depending on the size I give it in css (rather than working with a bar/meter of a fixed width).

Here is my javascript:

```
function showbar() {
    //GRAPHICS OF BAR
    sugarbar = document.getElementById('bar1');
    bar_width = parseInt($('#bar1').css("width"))
    $('#bar1').css({
        "height": "10px", "width": "300px", "border-radius" : "4px", "border": "1px solid #666633", "background-color": "cccc66" });

    //CALCULATION OF SUGAR LEVELS
    sugarunit = (parseInt($('#bar1').css("width")))/100;
    sugaramount = sugarunit*data.sugar;


    //MUST SET IMAGE HEIGHT
    barheight = "10" 

    //VALUE ON BAR
    bar_start = new Image();
    bar_start.src = "startcap.png";
    bar_start.height = barheight; 


    bar_middle = new Image();
    bar_middle.src = "midbar.png";
    bar_middle.height = barheight; 

    bar_end = new Image();
    bar_end.src = "endcap.png";
    bar_end.height = barheight;

    //IF THE SUGAR INTAKE IS LESS THAN THE PIXEL WIDTH OF THE STARTING CAP
    if (sugaramount<bar_start.width) {
        bar_start.width=sugaramount;
        sugarbar.appendChild(bar_start);
        sugarbar.appendChild(bar_end);
    }

    //IF THE SUGAR INTAKE IS BETWEEN THE WIDTH OF THE STARTING CAP AND BEFORE THE END CAP CAN BEGIN
    else if (sugaramount>=bar_start.width) {
        sugarbar.appendChild(bar_start);

        i = Math.floor(sugaramount-(bar_start.width+bar_end.width));

        for (j=1; j<=i; j++) {
            sugarbar.appendChild(bar_middle);
        }

        bar_middle.width = sugaramount%10;
        sugarbar.appendChild(bar_middle);
        sugarbar.appendChild(bar_end);
    }
}
```

Edit: to clarify, the appendChild does not want to include more than one instance of the image I have created. It only displays it once, even if I write sugarbar.appendChild(bar_middle); multiple times. Is there a reason for this?

EDIT2: I made a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7W6HY/1/ if you would like to try playing around with it

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to call this function each time the state changes. So, when the user inputs how much sugar that have consumed, that event needs to call this function:

```
var input = document.getElementById('yourinput');
input.addEventListener('blur', showbar, false);
```

Of course, I would recommend passing a paramater to your `showbar()` function that has the sugar amount.

Each time you call the function, though, you'll need to remove the other images (or hide them) from the DOM. Check if the image exists. If it does, then remove it (or hide it).

Comment: It doesn't change on input - it's a php POST form that I pass the values to javascript from so it only has one state